# Periods in Common Platform Enumeration WFN (NIST Interagency Report 7695 )

Tags: nist, enumeration, vulnerability-assessment

I’m looking at [NIST Interagency Report 7695](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/nistir/7695/final) and the grammar described in 5.3.2  seems to say that all `.` need to be preceded by a `\`, but this doesn’t seem to be followed in the CPE dictionary. Am I reading something wrong?

The examples in that section include

> "9\.?"
>
> "8\.??"
>
> "*8\.??"

However, the CPE dictionary doesn't seem to conform to this. For example, [cpe:2.3:a:sharp:rw-5100:1.1.0.0:*:*:*:*:windows_7:*:*](https://nvd.nist.gov/products/cpe/detail/375987?keyword=windows&status=FINAL&orderBy=CPEURI&namingFormat=2.3&startIndex=1380) has a version of 1.1.0.0 without a '\' preceding the '.'

Answer (score 1):

Later on in the document in the following text

> In a formatted string binding, the alphanumeric characters plus hyphen (“-”), period (“.”) and underscore (“_”) appear unquoted.

So this does appear to conform to the specification.